# set a default value inside parent schema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have nested schemas. And I want to set a default value of child schema inside parent schema. Here my schemas and what I tried:

```
const daySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    day: String,
    am1: periodSchema,
    am2: periodSchema,
    am3: periodSchema,
    pm1: periodSchema,
    pm2: periodSchema,
    pm3: periodSchema,
});


const programoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    monday: {
        type: daySchema,
        default: {
            ...daySchema,
            day: "Pazartesi",
        },
    },
    tuesday: daySchema,
    wednesday: daySchema,
    thursday: daySchema,
    friday: daySchema,
});
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply removing `...daySchema` issue will be solved.

```
monday: {
        type: daySchema,
        default: {
            day: "Pazartesi",
        },
    },
```

But when default value is dynamic like in your code, abetter solution is to create a function which accepts a default value and returns a schema like the code below.

```js
const periodSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  hour: {
    type: String,
    default: "00:00"
  }
});


const daySchema = function (defaultDay) { 
                      return {
                          type: new mongoose.Schema({
                                      day: String,
                                      am1: periodSchema,
                                      am2: periodSchema,
                                      am3: periodSchema,
                                      pm1: periodSchema,
                                      pm2: periodSchema,
                                      pm3: periodSchema,
                                  }),
                          default: {
                              day: defaultDay
                          }
                      }
}


const programoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    monday: daySchema("Pazartesi"),
    tuesday: daySchema(),
    wednesday: daySchema(),
    thursday: daySchema(),
    friday: daySchema(),
});

const Program = mongoose.model("programs", programoSchema);

console.log(new Program());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mongoose@7.2.3/dist/browser.umd.min.js"></script>
```